# A subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is connected means $X\backslash\lbrace z \rbrace$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know that this is true for any $z \in X$, but I am unsure of how to prove it.

I was thinking that the best approach would be to demonstrate that $X\backslash{z}$ is path connected, but I'm unsure how to state this in a way that would be reasonable.

Comment: I don't think this is true. $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know wrong. Taking $X=\mathbb R$ and $z=0$ proves the statement wrong.

More generally, if $n>1$, you can take

$$X=\{(t,0,0,0\dots,0)| t\in\mathbb R\}\\
z=(0,0,\dots,0)$$

to prove that the statement is false in all dimensions.

Comment: This probably explains why I was finding it difficult to prove, thanks